# Combine two counts in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, count

I have the following table ("Table") format

```
 A             B         C
"801331"    "5755270"   "0"
"1761861"   "10556391"  "1"
"1761861"   "10557381"  "33"
"1761861"   "11069131"  "33"
"801331"    "24348751"  "0"
"801331"    "77219852"  "0"
"1761861"   "557880972" "0"
```

And I would like to count and present two different quantities in one table grouped by column A.

The first is:

```
SELECT A, COUNT(*) FROM Table GROUP BY A
```

The second one has one condition:

```
SELECT A, COUNT(*) FROM Table WHERE C != 0 GROUP BY A
```

I want to have the following result

```
    A      1st  2nd
"1761861"  "4"  "3"
"801331"   "3"  "0"
```

I tried a few answers from questions such as [thisOne](https://stackoverflow.com/a/888774/2879450) yet I could not make it happen as the result is one row.

I get it is pretty easy, yet i cannot make it work.

Is there a (simple) way to do it?

Comment: why, according to your expected result, count(*) for a = 801331 equals 0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT A, sum(1),  sum(case when C <> 0 then 1 else 0 end) FROM Table  GROUP BY A;
SELECT A, count(*),  count(case when C <> 0 then A else null end) FROM Table  GROUP BY A;
```